# Block Diagrams in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, circuitikz

for my thesis i need to put some block diagrams in my LaTeX document. I was recommended to use TikZ for that.
[This](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/control-system-principles/) is the only sample code i could find.

Do you guys maybe have some tutorials / doc on that?

Especially i am interested in how to put graphical symbols into the boxes instead of text. 
And how to draw a dashed box around blocks.

Something like:

[image]

Comment: Here are two out of many relevant questions to get you started: [Left and right align inside one tikz rectangular node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55093/left-and-right-align-inside-one-tikz-rectangular-node) and more advanced but probably more helpful (in fact might be a duplicate : [Flow (or block) diagram tips?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17525/flow-or-block-diagram-tips). Search for block diagrams on this site too.

Comment: Look at thread [How to create new node shapes?](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4FA9626E.2000401%40googlemail.com&forum_name=pgf-users) from pgf-users mail list. There, Mark Wibrow show some examples of new blocks with drawings inside.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To put a drawing into a block, I advise you to create some macros with your drawings and put them in the nodes as in the example below

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\newcommand{\symbolA}{
\tikz \draw[red] (0,0)--(0,0.2)--(0.2,0.2)--(0.2,0.4)--(0.4,0.4);
}

\newcommand{\symbolB}{
\tikz[y={(0,-1)}] \draw[blue] (0,0)--(0,0.2)--(0.2,0.2)--(0.2,0.4)--(0.4,0.4);
}

\newcommand{\symbolC}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=green] (0,0) circle (0.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw](A) at (0,0){\symbolA};
\node[draw, right=2em of A] (B) {\symbolB};
\node[draw, right=2em of B] (C) {\symbolC};
\draw[-latex] (A) -- (B);
\draw[-latex](B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: node With images]

of course you can use it with the code you quote

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}


\newcommand{\symbolA}{
\tikz \draw[red] (0,0)--(0,0.2)--(0.2,0.2)--(0.2,0.4)--(0.4,0.4);
}

\newcommand{\symbolB}{
\tikz[y={(0,-1)}] \draw[blue] (0,0)--(0,0.2)--(0.2,0.2)--(0.2,0.4)--(0.4,0.4);
}

\newcommand{\symbolC}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=green] (0,0) circle (0.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {\symbolA};
    \node [block, right of=controller, pin={[pinstyle]above:Disturbances},
            node distance=3cm] (system) {\symbolB};
    % We draw an edge between the controller and system block to 
    % calculate the coordinate u. We need it to place the measurement block. 
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
    \node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
    \node [block, below of=u] (measurements) {\symbolC};

    % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y$}(output);
    \draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
    \draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
        node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: node images 2]

But you can also use the [Schemabloc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc) package: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/schemabloc/.

Comment: Nesting TikZ pictures is ... problematic.  One could just draw the symbols on top of the nodes afterwards, or do it the other way around: draw the node under the symbol.

Comment: hi Andrew, I don't understand "Nesting TikZ pictures is ... problematic. ",  Can you explain, with an example

Comment: for `\symbolC` the syntax can be reduced to `\tikz\draw.....`  rather than the existing -- is there some advantage to the existing syntax?